# Unity.Wcf / does not implement inherited abstract member AND no suitable method found to override

Tags: c#, wcf, inheritance, nuget, unity-container

This class was generated by NUGET after installing Unity.Wcf

```
public class WcfServiceFactory : UnityServiceHostFactory
    {
        protected override void ConfigureContainer(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            // register all your components with the container here
            // container
            //    .RegisterType<IService1, Service1>()
            //    .RegisterType<DataContext>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        }
    }
```

This is the class that is being inherited:

```
 public abstract class UnityServiceHostFactory : ServiceHostFactory
    {
        protected UnityServiceHostFactory();

        protected abstract void ConfigureContainer(IUnityContainer container);
        protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses);
    }
```

Somehow I keep getting these 2 errors:

> 'ServiceImplementation2.WcfServiceFactory' does not implement
>   inherited abstract member
>   'Unity.Wcf.UnityServiceHostFactory.ConfigureContainer(Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IUnityContainer)'

and

> 'ServiceImplementation2.WcfServiceFactory.ConfigureContainer(Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IUnityContainer)':
>   no suitable method found to override

There are no differences in the parameters.

Even autogenerating the method gets me errors.

I am using VisualStudio2013.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue when working with Unity 4.0.1, but then the issue was disappeared after downgrade to Unity 3.5.1404. Looks to me like Unity.Wcf doesn't work well with 4.0.1.

To install unity version 3.5

Install-Package Unity -Version 3.5.1404

Hope this help.

Comment: Hello this did the trick! I unistalled Unity.Wcf, then Unity and then I reinstalled them. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Instead of downgrading Microsoft.Practices.Unity, you can instead upgrade Unity.Wcf. I will guess you are using Unity.Wcf 1.0.0. By using this version of Unity.Wcf you will not get a compilation error:

[UnityWCF page at nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnityWCF/)

Comment: _Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline._

Comment: Sorry, link is documented now.

Comment: There are two versions of packages which help integrating Unity with WCF.One is called [Unity.WCF](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Wcf/) which has not been updated since 2012, and the other is [UnityWCF](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnityWCF/) which was last updated in 2016. I verified that Roath So's approach works. However, why downgrade to a previous version of Unity! I also verified that UnityWCF works well with the latest version of [Unity](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity/) 4.0.1 (updated in April 2014). I recommend using the approach suggested by @Ole.